# Why is the display image in Pictureedit/PictureBox not appropriate during the Focusrow event in GridView DevExpress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-gridcontrol

there is a problem if I use FocusedRow changes because the image that appears from the previous row still appears. Below I attach a screenshot. How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

[image: result1]
[image: result2]

```
Private Sub GridView1_FocusedRowChanged(sender As Object, e As FocusedRowChangedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.FocusedRowChanged
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)

        If view.FocusedRowHandle = GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SUBFOLDERP")?.ToString
        Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("FILENAME1")?.ToString
        Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("FILENAME2")?.ToString
        parentpathimage = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        Dim filePath1 = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename1, False)
        Dim filePath2 = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename2, False)
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath1) Then
            PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath2) Then
                PictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked the values in filePath1 and filePath2? Is maybe filePath2 empty?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič , for "ITM = TEST R 1000" has filepath1 only and "ITM = TEST R 1001" has filepath1 and filepath2. `Is maybe filePath2 empty?` yes you are right ,one of those items has an empty filepath2 how the image in the picture edit appears accordingly

Comment: Then you should handle the empty filePath2 -> clear the second image. It remains set now.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič , thanks for your reply how can I handle for an empty filepath